# How to provide external account parameter while creating managed account in stripe using php?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using stripe php library.

Here is my code:

```
$account = \Stripe\Account::create(
    array(
        "country" => "US",
        "managed" => true,
        "legal_entity" => array(
            'address' => array(
                'city' => 'Maxico',
                'country' => 'US',
                "line1" => 'H65',
                "line2" => 'standfort street',
                "postal_code" => '90046',
                "state" => 'CA'
            ),
            'business_name' => 'test business name',
            'business_tax_id' => '000000000',
            'dob' => array(
                'day' => '10',
                'month' => '01',
                'year' => '1988'
            ),
            'first_name' => 'Test',
            'last_name' => 'Tester',
            'personal_id_number' => '000000000',
            'ssn_last_4' => '0000',
            'type' => 'sole_prop'
        ),
        'tos_acceptance' => array(
            'date' => time(),
            'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        ),
        'external_account' => array(
            "country" => "US",
            "currency" => "usd",
            "account_holder_name" => 'Jane Austen',
            "account_holder_type" => 'individual',
            "routing_number" => "111000025",
            "account_number" => "000123456789"
        )
    )
);
```

This is the error I am getting:

> The external_account hash must include an 'object' key indicating what type of external_account to create.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Account::create response will include `external_accounts`,  why add that in there?

Comment: Stripe needs all the details for verification purpose. external_account for bank account transfers. if I don't provide this, the transfers will not be enabled.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) to create a [bank account token](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object) client-side, then use this token when creating the managed account. (This is the recommended way.)

Here's an example of a form using Stripe.js to create bank account tokens: https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/L2cefvtp/

and you'd update your code like this:

```
        ...
        'external_account' => 'btok_...' // token returned by Stripe.js
    )
```

Alternatively, you can pass the external account information from your server instead. **This is not recommended, as it increases the security risk of your application.** In this case, you must include the `'object' => 'bank_account'` key/value pair in the array:

```
        ...
        'external_account' => array(
            "object" => "bank_account",
            "country" => "US",
            "currency" => "usd",
            "account_holder_name" => 'Jane Austen',
            "account_holder_type" => 'individual',
            "routing_number" => "110000000",
            "account_number" => "000123456789"
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add stripe library first & then user the key to make object

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/stripe/init.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($this->privateKey);
```

Like this then you can create customer on stripe.

[Here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php) is library link.

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention in the code that I have given here. But it is there in my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, creating a token client side (with the Android SDK, iOS or StripeJS) then in your server side you pass the token to the external account

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_c7VExQZarF76Mm59HTcD7NLo");

stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount(
  "acct_1DO7wfJyhqKlvfeX",
  { external_account: "btok_1DZipAJyhqKlvfeXSA5OATY1" },
  function(err, bank_account) {
    // asynchronously called
  }

);
```