# PHP: Add external_account via Stripe Connect API?

Tags: php

I'm trying to add external_account via PHP API to stripe connect account.

I found this:

[How to provide external account parameter while creating managed account in stripe using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419252/how-to-provide-external-account-parameter-while-creating-managed-account-in-stri)

So I went ahead and made up my own code like this:

```
$acct = \Stripe\Account::create(array(
        "country" => "GB",
        "type" => "custom",
        "email" => "email@mail.com"
        'external_account' => array(
            "country" => "US",
            "currency" => "usd",
            "account_holder_name" => 'Jane Austen',
            "account_holder_type" => 'individual',
            "routing_number" => "111000025",
            "account_number" => "000123456789"
        )
    ));
```

But when I run that code, I get the following error:

```
[Sun Aug 13 05:30:21 2017] [warn] [client 82.43.186.69] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''external_account'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in /index.php on line 30
```

And line 30 is this:

```
'external_account' => array(
```

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Comment: I think there's a missing comma ',' after the email field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it was a simple missing `,` after the field "email".

```
$acct = \Stripe\Account::create(array(
      "country" => "GB",
      "type" => "custom",
      "email" => "email@mail.com"   // <--- missing ','
      'external_account' => array(
          "country" => "US",
          "currency" => "usd",
          "account_holder_name" => 'Jane Austen',
          "account_holder_type" => 'individual',
           "routing_number" => "111000025",
           "account_number" => "000123456789"
       )
   ));
```

Once you add that, the error goes away.

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Alright, will keep in mind for the future. Thanks for pointing this out.